# How to change the live value color to green when goes & to red when goes down?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

As you see in my code snippet below the price changes every second and I want to change also the color to green when price value goes up and to red when goes down. I tried to do this function by just using `Localhost` but no idea. Does it work using `Localhost`? Thanks and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
setInterval(function(){ 
$.getJSON("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/book", function(data){
  var current_price = data.asks[0][0];  $("#currentPrice").html(parseFloat(current_price).toFixed(2));
  });
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='currentPrice'></div>
```

Comment: You should cache your last price in cookies or localstorage to be able to compare it with latest price and it will be done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store previous numbers into a local var, and compare it with new numbers.

by default I have given red color to the numbers, and adding green class for green color, once the numbers is going up.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/book", function(data) {
    var prePrice = parseFloat($("#currentPrice").text()); // Stored previous price here
    var current_price = data.asks[0][0];

    $("#currentPrice").html(parseFloat(current_price).toFixed(2));

    // compare prices
    if (current_price > prePrice) $("#currentPrice").addClass("green");
    else $("#currentPrice").removeClass("green");
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
#currentPrice {
  color: red;
}

#currentPrice.green {
  color: green;
}


/* pseudo */

#currentPrice:after {
  content: '';
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:2px;
}

#currentPrice.green:after {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='currentPrice'></div>
```

Added `pseudo` element as bonus :p

Comment: Please, how to add a dollar sign "$" at the beginning of the price? I tried, but doesn't work with `setInterval` function, where it's shown and disappeared in a second.

Comment: you use pseudo element, `#currentPrice:before{content:'$'}`

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is not really necessary. This snippet is a [Minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In it the previous price is stored in a [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

```js
const lowerHigher = {
  lower: elem => elem.classList.replace("green", "red"),
  higher: elem => elem.classList.replace("red", "green"),
};

fakePrice();

function fakePrice() {
  const priceTag = document.querySelector("#price");
  const nwPrice = 1000 + Math.random() * 10000;
  const isLower = +priceTag.dataset.previousPrice < nwPrice;
  lowerHigher[isLower ? "lower" : "higher"](priceTag);
  priceTag.textContent = `${nwPrice.toFixed(2)} (previous ${(
    +priceTag.dataset.previousPrice).toFixed(2)})`;
  priceTag.dataset.previousPrice = nwPrice;
  setTimeout(fakePrice, 2000);
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="price" data-previous-price="0" class="red"></div>
```